# Is there a way to create a Period from an amount of a particular TemporalUnit?

Tags: java, java-time

It's trivial to create a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) as a given amount of given units:

```
Duration duration = Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

But there is no such method for [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html). What is the best way to do this?

I have a situation where i have a unit and a count as variables, so can't simply hardcode a call to Period::ofYear or similar.

This is the cleanest thing i came up with:

```
Period period = Period.from(new TemporalAmount() {
    @Override
    public long get(TemporalUnit unitToGet) { return unitToGet.equals(unit) ? amount : 0; }

    @Override
    public List<TemporalUnit> getUnits() { return List.of(unit); }

    @Override
    public Temporal addTo(Temporal temporal) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

    @Override
    public Temporal subtractFrom(Temporal temporal) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
});
```

This is clean in the sense that it avoids having to embed the knowledge of what units a Period can have, although this is probably excessively purist. It seems verbose for such a simple operation, though!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Period` does not support all temporal units, so a general method is not applicable there. It can be simulated, but only relative to a specific date:

```
LocalDate base = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
LocalDate added = base.plus(amount, unit);
Period period = Period.between(base, added);
```

Make sure you consider what happens with variable length months and February 29th, as this approach may not have the behaviour you desire.

Comment: `Duration` doesn't support all temporal units either, but it still has that factory method - it throws `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` for duff arguments.

Comment: duff: useless or broken (for non-native speakers like myself).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create factory for `Period`

```java
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class PeriodFactory {
    private static final Map<ChronoUnit, IntFunction<Period>> map = new EnumMap<>(ChronoUnit.class);
    static {
        map.put(ChronoUnit.YEARS, Period::ofYears);
        map.put(ChronoUnit.MONTHS, Period::ofMonths);
        map.put(ChronoUnit.DAYS, Period::ofDays);
        map.put(ChronoUnit.WEEKS, Period::ofWeeks);
    }

    private PeriodFactory() { }

    public static Period create(int amount, ChronoUnit unit) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(unit)).map(function -> function.apply(amount)).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Your implementation is great but should be moved to a separate class instead of defining anonymous implementation each time.

```java
public class UnitAmount implements TemporalAmount {
    private final TemporalUnit unit;
    private final long amount;

    private UnitAmount(long amount, TemporalUnit unit) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public static TemporalAmount of(long amount, TemporalUnit unit) {
        return new UnitAmount(amount, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public long get(TemporalUnit unit) {
        return this.unit.equals(unit) ? amount : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public List<TemporalUnit> getUnits() {
        return Collections.singletonList(unit);
    }

    @Override
    public Temporal addTo(Temporal temporal) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Temporal subtractFrom(Temporal temporal) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Usage will be clear and simple:

```java
        Period periodFactory = PeriodFactory.create(2, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
        Period periodUnitAmout = Period.from(UnitAmount.of(2, ChronoUnit.YEARS));
```

IMHO: In case of complex conversion or validation logic, if we will need to convert for example HOURS -> Period.DAYS factory is more flexible and extensible.

Comment: Very elegant factory. Thanks. (I’d declare the parameter `int amount` rather than `Integer amount`. If the reader prefers an exception in case of an unsupported unit, they can make the necessary modification themself.)